# Cassandra IN operator giving unpredictable results

Tags: cassandra, cql

I created a table like this:

`CREATE TABLE type_molist(typeid int, moid bigint, probeid bigint, modname varchar, status int, PRIMARY KEY(typeid, moid));`

When i query the table using IN operator, i got different results as below:

```
cqlsh:ngnms> select * from type_molist where typeid=158 and moid in (24,26);

 typeid | moid | modname       | probeid | status
--------+------+---------------+---------+--------
    158 |   24 | 192.168.1.251 |       2 |      5

(1 rows)

cqlsh:ngnms> select * from type_molist where typeid=158 and moid in (24,12);

(0 rows)
```

Since typeid=158 and moid=24 is a valid condition, i expect that one row to be retrieved. 
Is this a bug. I expect the output to be same as SQL query. 
I use cassandra 2.0.1.

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: FYI: I'm working on a single-node Cassandra 2.0.2 and both of your queries work correctly for me - both correctly return one row.

Comment: What consistency level are you using for reading/writing?  What is your replication factor and number of nodes?